# Start my Phonegap App at a specific Time (Alarm Clock)

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, phonegap-plugins

Ok, so I'm trying to make my Phonegap App start at a specific time, same functionality as an alarm clock. To this end i've tried to write my own plugin:

```
package de.ma;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult; 
import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;

public class alarm extends Plugin {
@Override
public PluginResult execute(String arg0, JSONArray arg1, String arg2) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // add 5 minutes to the calendar object
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReciever.class);
    intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "O'Doyle Rules!");
    // In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request code instead of 192837
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get the AlarmManager service
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

     return null;
}

}
```

But when compiling I get 3 errors:

1. `AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);` causes:

   > ALARM_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable    alarm.java
2. `Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReciever.class);` causes:

   > The constructor Intent(CordovaInterface, Class) is undefined alarm.java
3. `PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` causes:

   > The method getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (alarm, int, Intent, int)    alarm.java`

My receiver Java-File is called `AlarmReciever.java`.

If anyone sees what I'm doing wrong then I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing, I searched on phonegap alarm clock and found a plugin. Obviously it won't work for iOS.

Comment: To get the `ctx` (context) you can use `cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();`. Also [this tutorial](http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/) may help you on the way.

Answer (score 4):

Like @shaish said, first to create a Context reference so that you can do Android operation:.

```
Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

Use the context to create Intent, create PendingIntent and acquire system service.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReciever.class);
...
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
...
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Another issue is the AlarmReceiver class. It should be extending BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = AlarmReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceive()");
    }
}
```

And you need to put it into AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <application>
        ...
        <receiver android:name="de.ma.AlarmReceiver"/>
    </application>
```

Alternative to a BroadcastReceiver, if AlarmReceiver is an Activity, you can just use:

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

which launches your Activity directly.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've used for the alarm service is meant to be used in a context.
you should get the context (probably using something like:
    Context ctx = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().
)

and then on 1, use ctx.getSystemService, in 3 instead of passing this, pass ctx ,and instead of ALARM_SERVICE, write Context.ALARM_SERVICE.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with using the background service which will initiate the application on particular time.